# Nested class in IdentityUser

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

I have the following class

```
public class MyIdentityUser : IdentityUser {

    public UserNameInfo NameInfo { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class UserNameInfo {

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string SurName { get; set; }
}
```

I create a new `MyIdentityUser` succesfuly and push it to the database using Entity Framework but when i try to access to the information, NameInfo is always null.

In the DB the information exists and seems that its linked.

Comment: Thats because, [lazy loading is not yet supported by EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading). You could use [eager loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#eager-loading)

Comment: @tmg Can you give a simple example of the eager loading and where to use it?

Comment: Check the link, it has examples